# MySQL Remote Connection (Replication)

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, replication

I have the following topology. 
One Ubuntu 16.04. Instance on the Amazon AWS where my global MySQL Server is running. I want to use this Server as a Slave (Multi-Source Replication) for many local Master (Windows Machines MySQL Server).

For Testing Reasons I`ve Managed to make this running on one local Machine (with three different MySQL Server Running).

But now I want to make this Replication work on the mentioned global Server with the local ones. But it fails on the attempt to connect from the EC2 ubuntu Instance to the local Windows MySQL Server.

When I try to connect from my EC2 Instance to the local Computer with MySQL running on Port 3307 it keep saying:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on  (113)

The strange Part is, that I can PING the Local Computer but not telnet it.
Telnet just says: 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host

I can access the Global (EC2 / Ubuntu MySQL Server) from the local Machine but not the other way around.

I`ve already made a new Rule for this Port on the Windows Firewall Settings.

But the Port 3307 on the IPv4 Address seems to be still Closed.
[image: Picture to Check if a Port is Open]

I have no clue what I am missing to get a Connection from the EC2 Instance to my local Computer via TCP.

Do I have to open the Port Specific on the Router?

I hope for your help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your local computer is not visible, as your incoming ports to your local pc are closed. It may be a problem with your router, or your internet service provider, which is not allowing you to open ports(the most common one).

The possible solutions are:

1.) If your ports are not open due to the router

1. Try forwarding required ports to your pc.
2. Try Switching off your NAT firewall that may be blocking ports.
3. Try switching off your windows or antivirus firewall if any.

2.) If your ports are blocked by your Internet service provider.

1. Try getting help from ISP
2. Switch to a static IP connection if on dynamic.
3. Use a VPN service that provides an unblocked port service to all IPs.(This one solved my problem when I was struck in this situation.)

Comment: Hey :) 
Thank you for your answer. I have a question on the Point: 
3.)Use a VPN service that provides an unblocked port service to all IPs.
I have no clue on how this works. Do I have to install a VPN Service on my local Windows Machines and give it the right Ports etc of the local MySQL Server and then I`m able to access this mySQL Server from the outside? 

best regards.

Comment: I don't want to configure my Router, because the System will be used in many Situations and with different Router / Router specifications. I Hope there is a way to access these MySQL Server without changing them.

Comment: No in a good vpn service you will get all ports ready open that means whenever you run a service on a port it get open itself.And one more important thing is using VPN changes your external ip address

Comment: But where does this Service run? 
I found the OpenVPN Software. There I would make a VPN Server on my Ubuntu Server and Clients on my Windows Computer is that a right way to connect those or do you mean an external VPN Service where I register both Machines (Global Ubuntu and Local Windows Computer) and they are Connected via the external VPN Service? 
Are there free VPN Services for this procedures?

Comment: Sorry to ask this stupid Question but could you give an example on how a VPN Between the two Computers work?

Comment: VPN stands for Virtual Private Network which transfers all data from a client to VPN server via a secure tunnel which restricts remote requester to obtain original IP address of server or requester. In your case, I recommended this because in most cases an ISP does not provide open ports on Dynamic IP address, so to overcome that we can use VPN so that all traffic is routed through that VPN and we can get are ports open because generally, VPN puts no restrictions to ports.