# Is it possible to run web server on private IP?

Tags: sockets, ip, ethernet

I'm trying to implement a web server on my pc, connected to router.
Since my PC is connected to router, It identifies private IP address, starting with 
192.168...

However,it could not accept any clients that is not connected to the same router, even I specified tried with public IP address.
Is it possible to implement Web server that can be accept clients from anywhere with my PC connected to local router?

Or should I connect my web server directly to public IP directly without router?

It'll be pleasure to learn from your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be, that your web server routing may not be configured correctly to your external IP, or your web server ports may be blocked, or another possibility is that your firewall is blocking your service connections outside the local network.

So, a solution to misconfiguration would be, to forward your port to your internal IP of the web server from your router menu.

And, for the case of firewall blocking, you may give special access to your web server through the firewall by setting inbound and outbound rules.

And if all that is correct then most probably your ISP(Internet Service Provider) is not allowing ports to be opened to you, maybe due to dynamic IP or service restrictions.

For the similar problem, you may refer to my answer to another post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357679/mysql-remote-connection-replication/51360044#51360044)

Answer (score 0):

What router do you have?  go into the router using a web browser, mine is 192.168.0.1  with username and password as admin.  or username admin, password blank.

Then set a dmz route or for port forwarding 80 to you own internal IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! the problem was that  port forwarding port number of first router(which is connected to second router, second router connects to my server) wasn't set properly. I set it to port number of my server program, and I could access my server from outside.

Comment: But I have another question. I could access my server from outside my first router(with public IP address), but I couldn't access from clients connected to first router, with my public IP address. It works fine if I specify private IP address of second router(connected to my server)  to my client connected to first router. If you don't mind, could you teach me reason why?